# Superpowers/Magic and public safety

Tags: magic, politics, super-powers, ethics

So a common theme in superhero or fantasy stories is one where society decides people with powerful abilities are a threat and need to be regulated or "controlled" in some way. This is generally presented as a bad thing that violates their rights and freedoms.

My question is - what's a realistic solution to the fact that, yeah, no, having people walking around with the power to shoot fireballs out of their fingertips or vaporize a crowd with their laser eyes does run a risk that eventually one of them will turn into a mass-murdering supervillain, but is also a solution which doesn't involve imprisonment or forced servitude or other repressive means to stop people from potentially killing dozens of people in a blink of an eye?

Comment: So, what do you want here?

Comment: Suicide squad - [Look at this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/61236/why-do-governments-not-execute-or-otherwise-permanently-contain-super-villains) . Honestly I dont think there is a non repressive way because they are only human and humans are terrible. You either need a structure rewarding good(compeling to greed) or one punishing bad(inputting fear), preferably both.

Comment: I think the answer is it depends on all sorts of things such as which super power in particular amoung many other things. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Basic laws already punish you for killing, you still have the risk that somebody decides to kill anyway. The risk might be higher with powers but still, you kill, you go to prison. The only difference is that maybe a special police force and prisons are needed.